# Design DFA for $ (a + b(ba)^*)^*b$

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

I'm having some trouble to design a DFA that accepts the language defined by this regular expression

> $(a + b(ba)^*)^*b$

Can I say that $(a + b(ba)^*)^*$ is the same as $(a + b)^*$ ? Given this assumption, here is my DFA ("all strings over $\{a, b, \epsilon\}$ ending in $b$"):

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement that $(a + b(ba)^*)^*$ is the same as $(a + b)^*$ is correct.
Your DFA is correct, but is not minimal: you could identify states $q_1$ and $q_2$.

Comment: You're welcome.